# How to extract the substring from the end on the string?

Tags: python, string, split

I am trying to extract the timestamp from the end of my file name.

(Example file name:`ABC_xyz_march_2020.xlsx` or `xyz_mno__20_07_2019.xlsx`, `xyz_spa_20-07-2019.xlsx`, `xyz-mar_2019.csv`, `ABC-dec-5.csv`, etc)
(output: `march_2020`, `20_07_2019`, `20-07-2019`, `mar_2019`, `dec-5`, etc)

I am using the `split()` function of string but I do not extract the month in words.

Can anyone suggest a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

I don't often reach for regular expressions, but sometimes that's the right tool for the job:

```py
import re

PATTERNS = [
    re.compile(pattern)
    for pattern in (
        r"([A-Za-z]+_\d{4})\..*",  # {month_name}_{year}
        r"(\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{4})\..*",  # {day}_{month}_{year}
        r"(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\..*",  # {day}-{month}-{year}
        r"([A-Za-z]+-\d{1,2})\..*",  # {month_name}-day
    )
]

inputs = [
    "ABC_xyz_march_2020.xlsx",
    "xyz_mno__20_07_2019.xlsx",
    "xyz_spa_20-07-2019.xlsx",
    "xyz-mar_2019.csv",
    "ABC-dec-5.csv",
]

outputs = [
    "march_2020",
    "20_07_2019",
    "20-07-2019",
    "mar_2019",
    "dec-5",
]

for filename, expected_output in zip(inputs, outputs):
    for pattern in PATTERNS:
        match = pattern.search(filename)
        if not match:
            continue
        matched_date = match.group(1)
        if matched_date != expected_output:
            raise ValueError(
                f"In date {filename=}, got {matched_date=} instead of {expected_output=}"
            )
        print(f"Looked at {filename=} and found {matched_date=}")
        break
```

This builds a list of regular expression objects. Then for each input filename, it tries to match the filename against each regexp until one matches. Error handling (or deciding what to do if *no* patterns match) is left to the reader.